# How to make files from server streamable on website?

Tags: server, media

How to make files on my server accessable on website? I have videos on my server that I want to access from website. It would be ideal if I could also make them in directory structure that I have on server, I mean to make them appear in exact directory structure that I have on server, for example I have video in /export/home/vacation/2019/01_xyz.mp4 and I want it video to be displayed in "vacation" folder in website.

OS: OpenSUSE based - Rockstor

Web server on: Nginx, but I can use other as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the alias directive for location /vacation

```
server {

  index index.html;
  server_name test.example.com;

  root /web/test.example.com/www;

  location /vacation/ {
    alias /export/home/vacation/;
  }

}
```